# What are words like henceforth. nevertheless, hereupon?

Tags: meaning, legalese

what are these words? I think they are legal words and I wanna know more.

Comment: What did [Richard Snary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/275894) tell you?

Comment: Never mind. I found the answer in the similar thread.

Comment: @aman No you didn't. That answer is wrong.

Comment: Okay, then you tell me the right answer !